# NodeJS - Express bypass basicAuth

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I'm setting up dynamic routes and using basicAuth (when a user/pass has been configured). Here's what I have:

```
var basicAuth = express.basicAuth,
auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(req.params.project)) {
        var auth = config[req.params.project].auth;
        if (auth) {
            basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {
                // Check credentials
                callback(null, user === auth.user && pass === auth.pass);
            })(req, res, next);
        } else {
            // No authentication
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Then, my route looks like this:

```
app.get("/:project", auth, function (req, res) {
    ...
});
```

It's getting the config from a file which either contains the `auth` object with `auth.user` and `auth.pass` or is set to `false`. When set to `false` I'd like to (obviously) skip authentication.

The basicAuth is working when turned on, but I can't figure out how to dynamically bypass it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect doesn't check the return value of the middleware, so returning `true` doesn't mean anything. You need to call the `next` function so that Connect knows to continue.

```
var basicAuth = express.basicAuth,
auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(req.params.project)) {
        var auth = config[req.params.project].auth;
        if (auth) {
            basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {
                // Check credentials
                callback(null, user === auth.user && pass === auth.pass);
            })(req, res, next);
        } else {
            // No authentication
            next();
        }
    }
};
```

Also, it looks like the `basicAuth` callback can be synchronous, so it's probably cleaner to do this:

```
basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
    // Check credentials
    return user === auth.user && pass === auth.pass;
})(req, res, next);
```

Finally, `basicAuth` has another alternate form, so you can just do:

```
basicAuth(auth.user, auth.pass)(req, res, next);
```

Comment: Happy to help. Updated with a few other comments too.